# Computing coefficients of FIR filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have to create the function  `G(z) = [3*H^2(z)-2H^3(z)]*(z^-2)` which takes as an input the impulse response of the filter *H(z)* , and outputs the impulse response of *G(z)*.

I assume *H(z)* is a generic FIR filter

```
b = fir1(10,0.5); 
h = impz(b); 
t = impzlength(b);
```

where `h` is the values of the impulse response.
I think `H^2(z) = h(n).*z(-2n)` and `H^3(z) = h(n).*z^(-3n)`; `H(z)` is the transfer function of the filter .

I have to calculate the coefficients of num and den of the equation now, but I am stuck.
I thought at first to use `coeffs` and a for loop but i need also the zero coefficients, while `coeffs` only provides the non zero coefficients.

Now I thought that maybe there is a work-around for obtaining the coefficients: basically I have to select only certain values of `h`.
For example, to obtain the coefficients only for `z^-3n`:

```
n = 3; 
y = h(n:n:end);  % = 3 6 9 12 ...
```

But now **I can't figure out how to sum appropriately the coefficients** for `z^-3n` and `z^-2n`.

Comment: `conv` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using a non-standard notation, `H^2(z)` is not `h(n).*z(-2n)` but rather the multiplication of a polynomial with coefficients `h` with itself. This can be computed with:

```
H2 = conv(h, h);
```

Similarly, `H^3(z)` can be computed using:

```
H3 = conv(H2, h);
```

Then, summing the polynomials boils down to summing the coefficients, with the only catch that you have to pad `H2` so that the two vectors of coefficients have the same size:

```
H2 = [H2 zeros(1,length(H3)-length(H2))];
S  = 3*H2 -2*H3;
```

The final multiplication by `z^(-2)` (which can be represented by the polynomial coefficients `[0 0 1]`) could be achieve in the same way using `conv` with:

```
G = conv(S, [0 0 1 zeros(1,length(Sum)-3)]);
```

or alternatively, you may realize that multiplying by a single term polynomial is essentially equivalent to shifting the coefficients:

```
G = [0 0 S];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! You are right H^2(z) is conv(h,h) ,  i don't know why i did such a stupid error , you literally saved my day .